Why is my sand foaming when wet?
I got some sand from the township. They put it out for free near the local golf course for "sand bags".  I intended to use it for my children's sandbox.
I soaked it with water and a foam formed.  Any idea what could be causing this foam and whether it is safe for a play sandbox?



Sand bags are expected to be soaked/near nasty water and to be dumped afterwards.  The sand used for sand bags might not be the cleanest.

You should not rely on answers from this forum when the safety of your children is concerned and we cannot directly analyze your situation. Sand is cheap enough that you should buy some that is specifically made for sandboxes.

What you are seeing is the tiny particles mixed with air lifted to the top of the sand when water is added.  Not dissimilar to seafoam.  It's probably only a danger to anyone if they eat it. No different that the dirt outside your home.  Still, as others have said, Play-sand is not expensive.

15 cubic feet of play sand would be ~$400 at Home Depot.

Obviously the safety of the children is most important. Hence the question. There is a small set of possible answers which would convince me this is safe and nothing to worry about.

Sorry. $200 not $400.

It might be CO2 coming out of the sand. Also: have you looked at how generally not-great sandboxes are in the first place? They are a common parasite vector.

I would keep gently  applying water to it until it washed out the foaminess. And then probably spray it with diluted bleach.

Never been to the beach and seen the waves foam up on the sand?

I seem to remember that play sand is put through a wash to reduce small-particle impurities. You could do that with this sand, rinsing it bucket by bucket, but by the time you've done that I don't think it's a net bargain..

Update: I emptied out the sand from the OP, bought new play sand from home depot, and made the same hose-volcano for the kids. Result: foam. Apparently sand just foams.
